# iOS loads half images

Tags: ios, cordova

My app, done with PhoneGap, and it loads images from http server, where it load sometimes only half of an image, and the rest become gray. Very strange bug, and i have no idea how to fix this, is it iOS bug, or something is wrong with my app?

Comment: can you download the image prior to showing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the image is still being downloaded.
So before displaying it, check if it has been 100% downloaded.